# How to block a method while an asyncronous method is running without causing deadlocks in the UI thread

Tags: c#, async-await

I have several async methods that need to synchronize back to the main ui thread.

```
async Task MyAsyncMethod() {
    await DoSomeThingAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
    DoSomethingInTheGui();
}
```

now i need to call them from a syncronous event handler that is triggered from the gui thread, and the event handler cannot complete until the async method is done. so `MyAsyncMethod().Wait()` is not an option, neither is some kind of fire-and-forget solution.

This approach using Nito.AsyncEx seemed promising, but it still deadlocks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/249456

The only solution i've found seems like a hack to me:

```
public void RunInGui(Func<Task> action)
{
    var window = new Window();
    window.Loaded += (sender, args) => action()
       .ContinueWith(p => {
            window.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                window.Close();
            });
        });
        window.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

Is there a way to get the same effect (block the calling method, allow syncronization back to the gui thread) without creating a new window?

Note: I am aware that refactoring would probably be the best option, but that is a massive undertaking we have to do over longer time. Also worth mentioning that this is a plugin for Autodesk Inventor. The api has several quirks, and all API calls (even non-ui related) have to be executed from the main/ui thread.

Also worth mentioning is that we keep a reference to the main threads dispatcher and use `MainThreadDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ... )` all around the codebase.

Comment: You need to not block your UI thread.  So long as you have a requirement to block your UI thread (particularly while other processes actually need to use the UI thread) then you're going to be in a world of hurt.  Remove that requirement if you value your sanity.

Comment: *Why* use a synchronous event handler? Why not an *asynchronous& event handler? Eg `async void Button_Click(..){ await MyAsyncMethod1(); await MyAsyncMethod2();}`

Comment: Another option is to use Progress<T> to send messages back to the UI thread. The payload of a Progress<T> doesn't have to be a string or a progress message, it could be any object. Check [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: The problem is that the event handlers are not "mine". This is a plugin for Autodesk Inventor. I cannot use async void because the event handlers have out parameters: `void Eventhandler(..., out EventhandlingEnum handled)` and i need to make sure that the inventor host application does not continue before i my methods have completed

Answer (score 8):

> The only solution i've found seems like a hack to me

All sync-over-async solutions are hacks. I enumerate the most common ones in my [article on brownfield `async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). It's important to note that ***no solution exists for arbitrary code***. *Every* solution either deadlocks or throws in some situation.

One of the easier hacks is to block on a thread pool thread:

```
Task.Run(() => action()).Wait();
```

However, if your `action()` requires a UI context, then that won't work.

The next step is to attempt using a single-threaded context. This is the approach taken by my `AsyncContext` type:

```
AsyncContext.Run(() => action());
```

This would deadlock if `action` is waiting for the UI thread's message queue to be pumped. Since this deadlocks but `Window` works, this appears to be the case.

Dropping further down a level, you could use [nested pumping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx#Technical%20Details%20and%20Stumbling%20Points). Please note that [nested pumping opens up a whole world of hurt due to unexpected reentrancy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2004/02/02/apartments-and-pumping-in-the-clr/). There's some code on GitHub that shows [how to do nested pumping on WPF](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncCTPUtil/blob/master/AsyncTestUtilities/WpfContext.cs). However, I *highly* recommend that you refactor your code rather than embrace reentrancy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Refactoring is my preferred solution, but thats a massive undertaking, so it will have to be done gradually. How can i identify where my code is waithing for the UI threads message queue to be pumped?

Comment: @Henrik: You could use `AsyncContext` and then when it deadlocks take a look at the call stack on your UI thread.